# Property of a positive semi definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a positive semi definite matrix $A$, we can say that $$x^TAx\ge 0$$

For what kind of $x$ is the equality attained in the above inequality? What is the space of $x$'s for which the equality holds?

Answer (score 1):

The equality is attained for the vectors in $\mathrm{Ker}(A)$, i.e., the eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$. In this case $Ax=\lambda x= 0\cdot x = 0$, so $x^T A x = 0$.

Comment: You have not shown that the space of all such $x$ equals $\textrm{Ker}(A)$, since you have not ruled out the possibility that $Ax\not=0$ and yet $x^TAx=0$.

Comment: If the matrix is symmetric positive semi-definite then I think it's the only case possible (same as your updated answer). For non-symmetric matrices the notion of definiteness is not clear (complex e'vals?). For example if $A$ skew-symmetric then $x^TAx = 0$ for all $x$, but how do you define the definiteness of a skew-symmetric matrix (pure imaginary e'vals)?

Comment: the general definition of psd is that $x^TAx\geq 0$ for all $x$

Comment: Ok. Then we can't say much on the set of $x$ such that $x^TAx \ge 0$. For example, if $A$ is $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ skew-Hermitian then the set of $x$ such that $x^T A x = 0$ is $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

I will address the case of a *symmetric* positive semi definite matrix $A$, in which case after applying an orthogonal transformation one can bring the matrix $A$ into a diagonal form with non-negative diagonal entries $d_1,\ldots,d_n$, some of which may be equal to zero. Then the equality case is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n d_ix_i^2=0,
$$
which is equivalent to saying that $x_i=0$ for all $i$ such that $d_i\not=0$. Since the set of all such $x$ is seen to equal the kernel of the diagonal matrix in question, it follows (by change of basis) that for any symmetric psd $A$, the condition $x^TAx=0$ is equivalent to the condition $Ax=0$, i.e. the space of all such $x$ equals the kernel of $A$.

Note that symmetry of $A$ was crucial in this argument, and I am not convinced the same result holds for psd matrices that are not symmetric.

Comment: Thanks. I was specifically interested in symmetric case.

Comment: For nonsymmetric matrices the solution is the kernel of $A+A^T$, since $x^TAx=\frac12x^T(A+A^T)x$.